# CSS - make img behave like cover property

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using picturefill.js and the syntax it needs means I must use an `img` tag.

I want this image to behave like `background-size:cover` without js.

The parent container is already responsive and is 100% of the width and hight of the window.

*I feel like this should be pretty easy, but I'm just drawing a blank right now*

Thanks